# Missing network functionality on Clip Studio Paint (Wine)

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I use Clip Studio Paint through Wine 4.15 and Playonlinux on an Ubuntu 19.04 machine.

And while it works great locally, there are some features that require network access that just plain don't work, such as login in, the assets repository or auto coloring functions.

Launching it just leaves the part that should have web content blank, but it doesn't show an error saying it is offline (like it does when I do not have internet)

I don't know if I'm missing a dependency or if there is something else I need to configure. Link to the pastebin with the debug log:
https://pastebin.com/NffBbHRj

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new AskUbuntu user and I've been having a similar issue.

I think I have a possible solution: do you have the Internet Explorer components installed?

Clip Studio piggy backs on Internet Explorer for its online connection on Windows, so it stands to reason that it may need that component now.

Comment: That sounds promising, although I don't know how, when I select the IE6 or IE8 on the list for POL, it says "Error in source: AMD64 is set, but IE6 is needed"

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my end. This is because POL uses publicly available resources to add the components. Microsoft no longer has ie6 or 8 available publicly for 64-bit systems via download, however 32-bit downloads are still up. I personally have not had any success getting the 32-bit Wine versions and Clip Studio to work together. Maybe you'll have better luck while i try something else?